# Jquery Not Working On Woocommerce Product Variation Description

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I got two wooCommerce product variation dropdown: *Range* and *Textures*. User have to select one option from both dropdown and its echoed in `<p class="cdesc"></p>` within PHP. By default, the values are set to empty and when its get populated with a value. It creates Problem in css. So, When values are Shown in this section. I want to change CSS of `<div class="tooltip-help">`

It Works Fine On JsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/33shjyf6/ 
But not On my Wordpress Site. http://www.feature-wallpaper.co.uk/product/lamborghini-aventador/

```js
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

var range = $('#pa_range');
var texture = $('#pa_texture');

var checkSelection = function() {
  var rangeSelected = $("#pa_range option:selected")[0];
  var textureSelected = $("#pa_texture option:selected")[0];
  
  if (rangeSelected.index && textureSelected.index) {
    $('p.cdesc').text('Range:' + rangeSelected.value + ' Texture:' + textureSelected.value);
  } else {
    $('p.cdesc').text('');
  }
  
  if ($('p.cdesc').is(':empty')) {
    $(".tooltip-help").css({
      "margin-top": "45px"
    });
  } else {
    $(".tooltip-help").css({
      "margin-top": "145px"
    });
  }
}

range.change(checkSelection);
texture.change(checkSelection);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tooltip-help" style="margin-top: 45px;"></div>

<div class="variation-description">
  <p class="cdesc"></p>
</div>

<table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">
        <label for="pa_range">Range</label>
      </td>
      <td class="value">
        <select id="pa_range" name="attribute_pa_range" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_range">
          <option value="">Choose an option…</option>
          <option value="selfstick" class="attached enabled">SELFSTICK</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">
        <label for="pa_texture">Texture</label>
      </td>
      <td class="value">
        <select id="pa_texture" name="attribute_pa_texture" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_texture">
          <option value="">Choose an option…</option>
          <option value="canvas" class="attached enabled">Canvas</option>
          <option value="cotton" class="attached enabled">Cotton</option>
          <option value="smooth" class="attached enabled">Smooth</option>
        </select> <a class="reset_variations" href="#reset" style="visibility: visible; display: inline;">Clear selection</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress jquery format is not like regular jquery see here [why](https://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/)
Here is updated code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

    var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

    var range = $('#pa_range');
    var texture = $('#pa_texture');

    var checkSelection = function() {
      var rangeSelected = $("#pa_range option:selected")[0];
      var textureSelected = $("#pa_texture option:selected")[0];

      if (rangeSelected.index && textureSelected.index) {
        $('p.cdesc').text('Range:' + rangeSelected.value + ' Texture:' + textureSelected.value);
      } else {
        $('p.cdesc').text('');
      }

      if ($('p.cdesc').is(':empty')) {
        $(".tooltip-help").css({
          "margin-top": "45px"
        });
      } else {
        $(".tooltip-help").css({
          "margin-top": "145px"
        });
      }
    }

    range.change(checkSelection);
    texture.change(checkSelection);

});
```

Comment: This Doesnt Help Either.

Comment: Not Working Check Link http://www.feature-wallpaper.co.uk/product/lamborghini-aventador/ once and select options from both textures and range, it will show product description at top which will create problem for Section Named Help, that should be on same line when product description is showing.